# Idea: Как указать анализатору js/html на файлы внутри подключаемой библиотеки war или jar?

Tags: intellij-idea, настройка

Доброго времени суток.
Вопрос таков: некоторые js-файлы и др., лежат в библиотеке war. Анализатор кода их не видит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как указать анализатору дополнительные пути в подключаемые библиотеки и модули?